# Использование Queue<string> в многопотоке

Tags: c#

Вопрос, правильно ли будет использовать ReaderWriteLockSlim в таком случае

```
private Queue<string> _list;
private ReaderWriteLockSlim _lock

public string GetItem()
{
    _lock.EnterReadLock();

    try
    {
        return _list.Dequeue();
    }
    finally
    {
        _lock.ExitReadLock();
    }
}

public void SetItem(string item)
{
    _lock.EnterWriteLock();

    try
    {
        _list.Enqueue(item);
    }
    finally
    {
        _lock.ExitWriteLock();
    }
}
```

Что меня смутило, так это использование `_lock.EnterReadLock();` когда я получаю элемент из списка, нужно ли использовать `_lock.EnterWriteLock();` ведь коллекция `Queue<string>` изменяется?

Comment: [ConcurrentQueue<T>](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=netcore-3.1) - уже изобрели этот класс. И вы верно рассуждаете, что там где запись - надо write lock, то есть везде.

Comment: @aepot а точно, спасибо. Но вот что касательно вопроса. При получении элемента из коллекции надо использовать WriteLock?
Понял

Comment: Н получении, а извлечении элемента.